Fix "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null exception
After updating the Hibernate libraries. During startup, this exception is shown
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]enter code here

This is the configuration:
spring:
   schema: DB_SCHEMA


I would re-word the title to something like "<<org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null>> exception thrown after updating Hibernate" or just "NPE on Hibernate startup".

You upgraded what? You are using Spring Boot so upgrading Hibernate might not be possible due to supported versions, what is your configuration? Plese add the full stacktrace instead of just a snippet.
